# Managing NaN in target variables (testing)

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Please can someone advise me on how to handle NaN in my target variables set?

I've tried a variety of things but none is working. Here's what I've tried:

- Imputing zeros (0) in Y_test
- Replacing NaN with whitespace in the Y_test
- Emptying the Y_test

The dataset came already separated as training and test set. When I apply my logit classifier or any other classifier for that matter, it keeps returning a TypeError.

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean there are nans in the test set? The test set is the one you have to predict on, and thus the target variable is unkonwn for the whole test set. I'm a little confused with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't do supervised learning on unlabeled data. Either you discard those records or you have to go semi-supervised way.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "target variables set"?  The rest of your question refers to `Y_test`, which sounds like the test set. 
It's not clear from your question whether the missing values occur in the label or in one or more of the features.

As noted by @Piotr Rarus, if the missing values are in your label, then you must remove those examples from the test set.  Remember that the purpose of the test set is to evaluate the accuracy of your model, and you can't do that without labels.

If the missing value occurs in one of the features, you have several options:

- You can impute the missing value by taking the mean, median, or mode of the non-missing values.  Note that you should use statistics from the training set for imputation, not the test set.
- You can exclude that feature from the dataset.  This is a great option if the feature happens to be highly correlated with another feature.
- You can use a placeholder value to signify missing data.  The value of the placeholder depends on the data.  For continuous, standardized features, zero might be a good choice.  For categorical features, you need a special token to signify "missing".
- You can throw out the records with missing data

> When I apply my logit classifier or any other classifier for that matter, it keeps returning a TypeError. `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`

The [LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) model from scikit-learn requires all features to be numeric.  This error is expected if you have string or other non-numeric data types.

You can use [One-Hot Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) to transform your categorical features into numeric features.

> Emptying the Y_test

Yikes.  This is a poor solution because it eliminates your ability to evaluate your model.